# Can I catch file CREATION the operation in minifilter driver?

Tags: filesystems, minifilter

I don't know English well. Plz understand me. :)

In the File System Minifilter Driver, I want to redirect file path of the operation creating file.
So, I decided to use minifilter driver. I considered [simrep sample project](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/SimRep-File-System-9a4e2206) of MSDN. However, it is just showing like reparsing path.
I mean, if I save a file in C:\aaa\abc.txt, then the file will be saved in C:\bbb\abc.txt.
Just redirecting! And, though the driver will be detach and unloaded, abc.txt file will live in the C:\bbb\abc.txt.

Then, I want to catch the only the CAREATION operation in the callback routine handle IRP_MJ_CREATE.
I know that callback routine of IRP_MJ_CREATE is called by opening as well as creating the file, device, etc.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean creation of new file, then you can check for the following create disposition in pre create.

FILE_SUPERSEDED
FILE_CREATE
FILE_OVERWRITE
FILE_OVERWRITE_IF

all this disposition happens when there is new file being created.

Comment: Yes, You're right in case of create disposition is FILE_SUPERSEDED because FILE_SUPERSEDED means always create the new file.
But, the new file is created only if the file is not exist, in case of FILE_CREATE.
I tested by saving the file using NotePad.exe of Windows. Then, CreateDisposition values were presented 1~3. That means FILE_CREATE, FILE_OPEN, FILE_OPEN_IF. But, almost was FILE_CREATE. :(
I don't want to catch the file open operation